# Rails: Remote Form in a Partial: works once , not twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I've been confronted to a problem this last days.
I want to update an object using a remote form.
I can basically update my object when I submit my form the first time, but it doesn't work the second time.

So, I have a remote form in a partial.

view/missions/_table_form.haml.erb

```
%tr{:class => "tr_mission_#{mission.id} tr_mission"}
  = form_for(mission, :url => mission_path(mission), :html => { :remote => true , :method=> :put, :format => :js, :multipart => true, :class => "my_remote_form" }) do |f|
    = f.text_area :description,  :size => "220x6", :class => "fill_data"
    = f.submit  'Update', :class => "btn btn btn-inverse", :disable_with => "updating..."
```

This is my controller 
/app/controllers/missions_controller.rb

```
def update
    @mission = Mission.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
           render :action => "edit"
        }
        format.js {}
    end
  end
```

This is /missions/update.js.erb:

```
$('.tr_mission_<%= @mission.id %>').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "table_form", :locals => {:mission => @mission}).html_safe  %>');
```

The update of my object works once, not twice, On the firebug console, I can see that the type of my form is the first time: text/javascript and the next time it turns on text/html...

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: I could imagine that the UJS magic (creating the remote functionality from data-attributes) only happens when the page was loaded for the first time, but not when the form was loaded again through ajax.

Comment: seems you remove the form with your js.erb o?

Comment: I replace it with the same partial by using the function replaceWith (http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

Comment: Guys, I force my form to take a "put" parameter, not a post. I have to add this line in my form:    = hidden_field_tag '_method', 'put'

Answer (score 0):

For First time the javascript is freshly loading in your page. So it will work.
Next time your javascript is not working means you may be added your script code inside document.ready.......

For this issue you have two solutions:

1. You need to call javascript files once again on each update time.
2. You Specify your update calls in particular javascript function and you must call that javascript function on each update fires in your page.